# summation of column

Tags: vb.net, linq, sum

i have access database connected to vb.net database named T2 and it has 3 tables 
what i need is to find the summation of column name Qtyin from table 3 and put the result in 
text box i try using LINQ but there is something wrong :

```
Dim query = Aggregate Qtyin In T2DataSet.Table3 Into Sum()
        TextBox1.Text = query.ToString
```

Comment: You don't need to include tag names in title on SO, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about Method-based query, instead of syntax-based one?

```
Dim sum = T2DataSet.Table3.Sum(Function(i) i.Qtyin)
TextBox1.Text = sum
```